# How do I exclude any results with permission denied when using the find command?

Tags: find

So I am trying to find any file containing the name IDLE. This is the command I used:

```
find / -xdev -name "IDLE.*" -type f -ls > IDLE_find.txt
```

The output in the console just gives me a bunch of directories where I didn't have enough permission. How do I filter out so it's clear what the find command actually found? I am aware that there is no file called "IDLE.*" but then it should just return an empty console.

[image: bash]

However what is weird is that when I open the file that I wrote the output to it is empty.

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find / -xdev -name "IDLE.*" -type f -ls > IDLE_find.txt 2> /dev/null
```

Should do the trick. Alternatively run the command via `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
`find /path/to/dir -name "search-patter"  2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"`

Answer (score 0):

try using sudo the following
`find / -xdev -name "IDLE.*" -type f -ls > IDLE_find.txt 2> /dev/null`